# Used "VisualStudioUninstaller" GitHub to (un)install Visual Studio 2016 completely but failed(cmd closed). How do I complete (un)installation now?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uninstallation

I am using Windows 10 and was using *"VisualStudioUninstaller"* from GitHub to (un)install Visual Studio 2016 completely.
As per the instructions, I ran ***Setup.ForcedUninstall.exe*** file, which started (un)installing process in command prompt(cmd).
I pressed ***Ctrl + C*** in cmd.exe when it was (un)installing 10/60th instance (that's what I remember). **The cmd.exe automatically closed after that.**

I can still see the following programs in Programs and Features list:

- MVS 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64)
- MVS 2015 Shell (Isolated)
- MVS Tools for Applications 2015
- MVS Tools for Applications 2015 Language support

**What do I do to uninstall them completely? Can I run the Setup.ForcedUninstall.exe file again to complete the remaining instances?**

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow. But, yes, just run that app again

Comment: Hi Divyansh, you can run this Setup.ForcedUninstall.exe for several times or restart the computer to re-run, if the above items still appear under the Programs and Features, right click it and choose ‘Uninstall’ to manually remove them. I tried it on my side and it removed the VS 2015 and most of the related components, but some common shared components like Visual C++ 2015 redistributable and .NET Framework versions not be removed since some other software maybe reference them, not found those items that you provided, please try to manually uninstall them.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Thank you, Sara & Igor. (:

Comment: @Divyansh, does your issue is solved or not? If not, please feel free to let me know. If it is fixed, could you please share your solution as a reply and mark it, it will help other community members who meet the same or similar issue, thanks :)